# how to fix the pwgui installation error

Tags: command-line, xubuntu

Command 'pwgui' not found, did you mean:

command 'p2wgui' from deb pgn2web (0.4-3build1)

Try: sudo apt install

Comment: That's not an installation error. Usually, that response means that pwgui is not installed at all. You need to tell us more about exactly what you installed, and how.

Comment: Open [this link](http://www-k3.ijs.si/kokalj/pwgui/install.html) and scroll down. Have you taken those steps?

Comment: i just installed ubuntu on vmware then according to what i ve learned from a workshop installed gfortran, mpich and QE.                                       maryam@maryam-virtual-machine:~$ cd /home/maryam/Downloads/PWgui-6.1
maryam@maryam-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/PWgui-6.1$ pwgui

Command 'pwgui' not found, did you mean:

  command 'p2wgui' from deb pgn2web (0.4-3build1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name> this is what i ve done like the command i learned from the workshop but it dosent work for me what should i do?@user535733@KGIII

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue.
First, to go your `PWgui` folder installation,

mine
`cd PWgui-6.1`

then type a command
`./pwgui` to launch.

Good luck!

[ss pwgui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJWLd.png)